# how to send a class from a window(window1) to its owned window (window2)

Tags: c#, xaml

Code of window1, this class create window2 and create the event that i want to send to windows2

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{   //my event
    public class modificoHojaEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public ClaseHoja miHoja;
    }

    public delegate void modificoHojaEventHandler(object sender, 
    modificoHojaEventArgs e);
    public event modificoHojaEventHandler ModificoHojaHandler;
    protected virtual void OnAceptoHoja(modificoHojaEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.ModificoHojaHandler != null)
            this.ModificoHojaHandler(this, e);
    } 
     //constructor
     public Window1()
     {
      InitializeComponent();
     }
     //create window2 w2 and send argumentos to w2
      private void BotonModificar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        window2 w2 = new window2();
        w2.Owner = this;
        w2.ShowDialog();
        modificoHojaEventArgs argumentos = new modificoHojaEventArgs();
        argumentos.miHoja = data;
        OnAceptoHoja(argumentos);

    }
```

Code of window2 where i want to receive argumentos

```
 public partial class DatosDeLaHoja : Window
{
  public DatosDeLaHoja( )
    {

        Window1 winn = new Window1();
```

This is my problem, i can't obtain the window1 from this window2 was created

```
        winn=(Window1)PresentationSource.FromVisual(this).RootVisual
        winn.ModificoHojaHandler += winn_modifico;

        InitializeComponent();
      }


//receive argumentos using e variable
    void winn_modifico(object sender, Window1.modificoHojaEventArgs e)
    {
        cHoja = e.miHoja;


    }
```

Comment: Pass the `Window1` object as a parameter to `DatosDeLaHoja`'s constructor.

Answer (score 0):

in windows 2 create this

```
public Window window1 {get; set; }
```

then on window 1

```
private void BotonModificar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        window2 w2 = new window2();
w2.window1 = this;
        w2.Owner = this;
        w2.ShowDialog();
        modificoHojaEventArgs argumentos = new modificoHojaEventArgs();
        argumentos.miHoja = data;
        OnAceptoHoja(argumentos);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you intend to achieve by doing this however, you simply should pass an argument into **DatosDeLaHoja( )** The argument obviously should be the **window1** object